# Adding new Class to One Shot Learning trained model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, cluster-analysis, dotnetnuke, siamese-network

I'm new in One-Shot Learning and my information isn't complete yet. I did not find the answers to these questions in the internet search.

1. After training the network in One-Shot Learning, to add new Class with the new single data, should the network be trained from the beginning completely?
2. If no, Does this update require previous data and how it happens?

Thanks